# Prefill text field based on link selections

Tags: javascript

Have a form with an empty text field. Above that will be 4 html buttons. When choosing any of the first three, it should prefill the empty input with that value and focus on the field. For example if I click $10, it should fill the empty field with a value of $10 and bring focus to that field. If I then click $100 it would replace the field value with $100 and bring focus to the field.

Finally, if choosing other, it should bring focus to the field but make leave the field empty or make it empty if it has a value.

Found some options with jQuery but was trying to find a clean option with javascript only. Otherwise can add jQuery if necessary.

I have full control of the class, ids and such. Assuming the option will involve onclick. Found a couple options on SO but they seemed a bit more complex than necessary.

```
<a href="" class="" id="" />$1</a>
<a href="" class="" id="" />$10</a>
<a href="" class="" id="" />$100</a>
<a href="" class="" id="" />Other</a>

<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="" value="">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: your text field is also hidden, so you cannot bring focus to it

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli My bad, I've updated the sample code accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a plain JavaScript way:

```js
var linx = document.querySelectorAll("a")
for (i = 0; i < linx.length; i++) {
  linx[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.querySelector('[type="text"]').value = (this.innerHTML != 'Other') ? this.innerHTML : '';
    document.querySelector('[type="text"]').focus()
  });
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="" id="">$1</a>
<a href="" class="" id="">$10</a>
<a href="" class="" id="">$100</a>
<a href="" class="" id="">Other</a>

<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="" value="">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Wow this is perfect. Have been sending a few hours and was going about it in a much different more complicated way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am posting a jQuery solution (for simplicity) although the change would be trivial to no-jQuery (*but require more keystrokes*)

```js
$('.predefined').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var value = $(this).data('value');
  
  $('.predefined-target').val(value).focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="#" class="predefined" data-value="1"/>$1</a>
<a href="#" class="predefined" data-value="10" />$10</a>
<a href="#" class="predefined" data-value="100" />$100</a>
<a href="#" class="predefined" data-value="" />Other</a>

<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" class="predefined-target" name="whatever" value="">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```